# More functional approach to xml parsing

Tags: xml, scala

I am mapping some xml to a case class and it works fine, but I have a feeling that my imperative blinkers are blinding me to a better functional solution. Can anyone suggest a better way than this:

```
def buildAddress(geocodeResponse: NodeSeq) : Address = {
  val addressNodes = geocodeResponse \\ "address_component"
  var street = " "
  var town = ""
  var suburb = ""
  var province = ""
  var country = ""
  var postalCode = ""

  addressNodes.foreach {node =>      
    val typeString = (node \ "type").head.text
    if ("street_number" ==  typeString) {
      street = (node \ "long_name").text + street
    }
    else if ("route" == typeString) {
      street = street + (node \ "long_name").text
    }
    else if ("locality" == typeString) {
      town = (node \ "long_name").text
    }
    else if ("sublocality" == typeString) {
      suburb = (node \ "long_name").text
    }
    else if ("administrative_area_level_1" == typeString) {
      province = (node \ "long_name").text
    }
    else if ("country" == typeString) {
      country =  (node \ "long_name").text
    }
    else if ("postal_code" == typeString) {
      town = (node \ "long_name").text
    }
  }
  Address(street,suburb,town,province,country,postalCode)
}
```

The xml in this case is retrieved from he Google geo-coding api, using Dispatch.

```
   import dispatch._ 
   def lookupAddress(lat: Double, long: Double): Address = {
     val position = lat.toString + "," + long.toString
     val req = url("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml") <<? Map("latlng" -> position, "sensor" -> "true")
     Http(req </> {
     nodes => buildAddress(nodes)
     })
   }
```

The xml result looks like this:

```
    <GeocodeResponse>
      <status>OK</status>
      <result>
        <type>street_address</type>
        <formatted_address>3 Louw St, Stellenbosch 7600, South Africa</formatted_address>
        <address_component>
          <long_name>3</long_name>
          <short_name>3</short_name>
          <type>street_number</type>
        </address_component>
        <address_component>
          <long_name>Louw St</long_name>
          <short_name>Louw St</short_name>
          <type>route</type>
        </address_component>
        <address_component>
          <long_name>Stellenbosch Central</long_name>
          <short_name>Stellenbosch Central</short_name>
          <type>sublocality</type>
          <type>political</type>
        </address_component>
        <address_component>
          <long_name>Stellenbosch</long_name>
          <short_name>Stellenbosch</short_name>
          <type>locality</type>
          <type>political</type>
        </address_component>
        <address_component>
          <long_name>Stellenbosch</long_name>
          <short_name>Stellenbosch</short_name>
          <type>administrative_area_level_3</type>
          <type>political</type>
        </address_component>
        <address_component>
          <long_name>Brede River DC</long_name>
          <short_name>Brede River DC</short_name>
          <type>administrative_area_level_2</type>
          <type>political</type>
        </address_component>
        <address_component>
          <long_name>Western Cape</long_name>
          <short_name>WC</short_name>
          <type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
          <type>political</type>
        </address_component>
        <address_component>
          <long_name>South Africa</long_name>
          <short_name>ZA</short_name>
          <type>country</type>
          <type>political</type>
        </address_component>
        <address_component>
          <long_name>7600</long_name>
          <short_name>7600</short_name>
          <type>postal_code</type>
        </address_component>
        <geometry>
          <location>
            <lat>-33.9403990</lat>
            <lng>18.8610090</lng>
          </location>
          <location_type>ROOFTOP</location_type>
          <viewport>
            <southwest>
              <lat>-33.9435466</lat>
              <lng>18.8578614</lng>
            </southwest>
            <northeast>
              <lat>-33.9372514</lat>
              <lng>18.8641566</lng>
            </northeast>
          </viewport>
        </geometry>
      </result>
      <result>
        <type>sublocality</type>
        <type>political</type>
        <formatted_address>Stellenbosch Central, Stellenbosch, South Africa</formatted_address>
        <address_component>
          <long_name>Stellenbosch Central</long_name>
          <short_name>Stellenbosch Central</short_name>
          <type>sublocality</type>
          <type>political</type>
        </address_component>
        <address_component>
          <long_name>Stellenbosch</long_name>
          <short_name>Stellenbosch</short_name>
          <type>locality</type>
          <type>political</type>
        </address_component>
        <address_component>
          <long_name>Stellenbosch</long_name>
          <short_name>Stellenbosch</short_name>
          <type>administrative_area_level_3</type>
          <type>political</type>
        </address_component>
        <address_component>
          <long_name>Brede River DC</long_name>
          <short_name>Brede River DC</short_name>
          <type>administrative_area_level_2</type>
          <type>political</type>
        </address_component>
        <address_component>
          <long_name>Western Cape</long_name>
          <short_name>WC</short_name>
          <type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
          <type>political</type>
        </address_component>
        <address_component>
          <long_name>South Africa</long_name>
          <short_name>ZA</short_name>
          <type>country</type>
          <type>political</type>
        </address_component>
        <geometry>
          <location>
            <lat>-33.9354048</lat>
            <lng>18.8640607</lng>
          </location>
          <location_type>APPROXIMATE</location_type>
          <viewport>
            <southwest>
              <lat>-33.9437180</lat>
              <lng>18.8449199</lng>
            </southwest>
            <northeast>
              <lat>-33.9230960</lat>
              <lng>18.8778929</lng>
            </northeast>
          </viewport>
          <bounds>
            <southwest>
              <lat>-33.9437180</lat>
              <lng>18.8449199</lng>
            </southwest>
            <northeast>
              <lat>-33.9230960</lat>
              <lng>18.8778929</lng>
            </northeast>
          </bounds>
        </geometry>
      </result>
      <result>
        <type>postal_code</type>
        <formatted_address>7599, South Africa</formatted_address>
        <address_component>
          <long_name>7599</long_name>
          <short_name>7599</short_name>
          <type>postal_code</type>
        </address_component>
        <address_component>
          <long_name>Brede River DC</long_name>
          <short_name>Brede River DC</short_name>
          <type>administrative_area_level_2</type>
          <type>political</type>
        </address_component>
        <address_component>
          <long_name>Western Cape</long_name>
          <short_name>WC</short_name>
          <type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
          <type>political</type>
        </address_component>
        <address_component>
          <long_name>South Africa</long_name>
          <short_name>ZA</short_name>
          <type>country</type>
          <type>political</type>
        </address_component>
        <geometry>
          <location>
            <lat>-33.9300286</lat>
            <lng>18.8640607</lng>
          </location>
          <location_type>APPROXIMATE</location_type>
          <viewport>
            <southwest>
              <lat>-33.9693080</lat>
              <lng>18.8019200</lng>
            </southwest>
            <northeast>
              <lat>-33.8700550</lat>
              <lng>18.9232900</lng>
            </northeast>
          </viewport>
          <bounds>
            <southwest>
              <lat>-33.9693080</lat>
              <lng>18.8019200</lng>
            </southwest>
            <northeast>
              <lat>-33.8700550</lat>
              <lng>18.9232900</lng>
            </northeast>
          </bounds>
        </geometry>
      </result>
      <result>
        <type>locality</type>
        <type>political</type>
        <formatted_address>Stellenbosch, South Africa</formatted_address>
        <address_component>
          <long_name>Stellenbosch</long_name>
          <short_name>Stellenbosch</short_name>
          <type>locality</type>
          <type>political</type>
        </address_component>
        <address_component>
          <long_name>Stellenbosch</long_name>
          <short_name>Stellenbosch</short_name>
          <type>administrative_area_level_3</type>
          <type>political</type>
        </address_component>
        <address_component>
          <long_name>Brede River DC</long_name>
          <short_name>Brede River DC</short_name>
          <type>administrative_area_level_2</type>
          <type>political</type>
        </address_component>
        <address_component>
          <long_name>Western Cape</long_name>
          <short_name>WC</short_name>
          <type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
          <type>political</type>
        </address_component>
        <address_component>
          <long_name>South Africa</long_name>
          <short_name>ZA</short_name>
          <type>country</type>
          <type>political</type>
        </address_component>
        <geometry>
          <location>
            <lat>-33.9366667</lat>
            <lng>18.8613889</lng>
          </location>
          <location_type>APPROXIMATE</location_type>
          <viewport>
            <southwest>
              <lat>-34.0150869</lat>
              <lng>18.7658819</lng>
            </southwest>
            <northeast>
              <lat>-33.8782960</lat>
              <lng>18.9232900</lng>
            </northeast>
          </viewport>
          <bounds>
            <southwest>
              <lat>-34.0150869</lat>
              <lng>18.7658819</lng>
            </southwest>
            <northeast>
              <lat>-33.8782960</lat>
              <lng>18.9232900</lng>
            </northeast>
          </bounds>
        </geometry>
      </result>
      <result>
        <type>postal_code</type>
        <formatted_address>7600, South Africa</formatted_address>
        <address_component>
          <long_name>7600</long_name>
          <short_name>7600</short_name>
          <type>postal_code</type>
        </address_component>
        <address_component>
          <long_name>Western Cape</long_name>
          <short_name>WC</short_name>
          <type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
          <type>political</type>
        </address_component>
        <address_component>
          <long_name>South Africa</long_name>
          <short_name>ZA</short_name>
          <type>country</type>
          <type>political</type>
        </address_component>
        <geometry/>
      </result>
      <result>
        <type>administrative_area_level_3</type>
        <type>political</type>
        <formatted_address>Stellenbosch, South Africa</formatted_address>
        <address_component>
          <long_name>Stellenbosch</long_name>
          <short_name>Stellenbosch</short_name>
          <type>administrative_area_level_3</type>
          <type>political</type>
        </address_component>
        <address_component>
          <long_name>Brede River DC</long_name>
          <short_name>Brede River DC</short_name>
          <type>administrative_area_level_2</type>
          <type>political</type>
        </address_component>
        <address_component>
          <long_name>Western Cape</long_name>
          <short_name>WC</short_name>
          <type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
          <type>political</type>
        </address_component>
        <address_component>
          <long_name>South Africa</long_name>
          <short_name>ZA</short_name>
          <type>country</type>
          <type>political</type>
        </address_component>
        <geometry>
          <location>
            <lat>-33.9405478</lat>
            <lng>18.9502232</lng>
          </location>
          <location_type>APPROXIMATE</location_type>
          <viewport>
            <southwest>
              <lat>-34.0633899</lat>
              <lng>18.7083300</lng>
            </southwest>
            <northeast>
              <lat>-33.7933599</lat>
              <lng>19.2438000</lng>
            </northeast>
          </viewport>
          <bounds>
            <southwest>
              <lat>-34.0633899</lat>
              <lng>18.7083300</lng>
            </southwest>
            <northeast>
              <lat>-33.7933599</lat>
              <lng>19.2438000</lng>
            </northeast>
          </bounds>
        </geometry>
      </result>
      <result>
        <type>administrative_area_level_2</type>
        <type>political</type>
        <formatted_address>Brede River DC, South Africa</formatted_address>
        <address_component>
          <long_name>Brede River DC</long_name>
          <short_name>Brede River DC</short_name>
          <type>administrative_area_level_2</type>
          <type>political</type>
        </address_component>
        <address_component>
          <long_name>Western Cape</long_name>
          <short_name>WC</short_name>
          <type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
          <type>political</type>
        </address_component>
        <address_component>
          <long_name>South Africa</long_name>
          <short_name>ZA</short_name>
          <type>country</type>
          <type>political</type>
        </address_component>
        <geometry>
          <location>
            <lat>-33.4220698</lat>
            <lng>19.7591675</lng>
          </location>
          <location_type>APPROXIMATE</location_type>
          <viewport>
            <southwest>
              <lat>-34.1172599</lat>
              <lng>18.7083299</lng>
            </southwest>
            <northeast>
              <lat>-32.1844899</lat>
              <lng>21.0103399</lng>
            </northeast>
          </viewport>
          <bounds>
            <southwest>
              <lat>-34.1172599</lat>
              <lng>18.7083299</lng>
            </southwest>
            <northeast>
              <lat>-32.1844899</lat>
              <lng>21.0103399</lng>
            </northeast>
          </bounds>
        </geometry>
      </result>
      <result>
        <type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
        <type>political</type>
        <formatted_address>Western Cape, South Africa</formatted_address>
        <address_component>
          <long_name>Western Cape</long_name>
          <short_name>WC</short_name>
          <type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
          <type>political</type>
        </address_component>
        <address_component>
          <long_name>South Africa</long_name>
          <short_name>ZA</short_name>
          <type>country</type>
          <type>political</type>
        </address_component>
        <geometry>
          <location>
            <lat>-33.2277918</lat>
            <lng>21.8568586</lng>
          </location>
          <location_type>APPROXIMATE</location_type>
          <viewport>
            <southwest>
              <lat>-34.8330538</lat>
              <lng>17.7575638</lng>
            </southwest>
            <northeast>
              <lat>-30.4302599</lat>
              <lng>24.2224100</lng>
            </northeast>
          </viewport>
          <bounds>
            <southwest>
              <lat>-34.8330538</lat>
              <lng>17.7575638</lng>
            </southwest>
            <northeast>
              <lat>-30.4302599</lat>
              <lng>24.2224100</lng>
            </northeast>
          </bounds>
        </geometry>
      </result>
      <result>
        <type>country</type>
        <type>political</type>
        <formatted_address>South Africa</formatted_address>
        <address_component>
          <long_name>South Africa</long_name>
          <short_name>ZA</short_name>
          <type>country</type>
          <type>political</type>
        </address_component>
        <geometry>
          <location>
            <lat>-30.5594820</lat>
            <lng>22.9375060</lng>
          </location>
          <location_type>APPROXIMATE</location_type>
          <viewport>
            <southwest>
              <lat>-34.9670000</lat>
              <lng>16.2817000</lng>
            </southwest>
            <northeast>
              <lat>-22.1253869</lat>
              <lng>33.0469000</lng>
            </northeast>
          </viewport>
          <bounds>
            <southwest>
              <lat>-34.9670000</lat>
              <lng>16.2817000</lng>
            </southwest>
            <northeast>
              <lat>-22.1253869</lat>
              <lng>33.0469000</lng>
            </northeast>
          </bounds>
        </geometry>
      </result>
    </GeocodeResponse>
```

Comment: Could you post an example XML of an address_component node? Thanks

Comment: See also [Marshalling/unmarshalling XML in Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664286/marshalling-unmarshalling-xml-in-scala)

Comment: The xml in this case is retrieved from he Google geo-coding api, using Dispatch.
  
 import dispatch._ 
 def lookupAddress(lat: Double, long: Double): Address = {
    val position = lat.toString + "," + long.toString
    val req = url("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml") <<? Map("latlng" -> position, "sensor" -> "true")
    Http(req </> {
      nodes => buildAddress(nodes)
    })
  }

Comment: I am attaching the code as an answer since the comment does not allow for long code segments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you get some kind of reflection, there really isn't much you can do to make it better. It seems you could improve how you match your attributes, doing something like this, to help with the sheer drudgery of it:

```
def buildAddress(geocodeResponse: NodeSeq) : Address = {
    def getComponent(component: String): String = {
        val longNames = for {
            addressComponent <- geocodeResponse \\ "address_component"
            componentType <- addressComponent \ "type"
            if componentType.text == component
        } yield addressComponent \ "long_name"
        longNames.head.text
    }
    implicit def toC(s: String) = new { def c = getComponent(s) }
    implicit val map = Map(
        'street -> ("route".c + "street_number".c),
        'town -> "locality".c,
        'suburb -> "sublocality".c,
        'province -> "administrative_area_level_1".c,
        'country -> "country".c,
        'postalCode -> "postal_code".c
    )
    Address('street, 'suburb, 'town, 'province, 'country, 'postalCode)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - if not improving the actual code, your answer give met a much better handle on the use of implicit functions. Funny how abstract stuff suddenly becomes clear when you have a practical use. I had to include a further filter because the google geo-coding api actually could return more than one result nodes as you can see from the example xml I included in my question.

Comment: Nice, but it also illustrates the limitations of Scala's XML matching :( It would be nice to have a bit more of XPath in there...

Answer (score 4):

Not really more functional, but a match cleans things up a bit. Given you have to look for specific strings, and the rules for dealing with the value depends on the string, I'm not sure how much more "functional" it can be.

```
def buildAddress(geocodeResponse: NodeSeq) : Address = {
  val addressNodes = geocodeResponse \\ "address_component"
  var street = " "
  var town = ""
  var suburb = ""
  var province = ""
  var country = ""
  var postalCode = ""

  addressNodes.foreach {node =>      
      lazy val text = (node \ "long_name").text  // lazy so we don't look until we know it should be there
    (node \ "type").head.text match {
        case "street_number" => street =  text + street
        case "route"         => street = street + text
        case "locality"      => town =  text
        case "sublocality"   => suburb = text
        case "administrative_area_level_1" => province = text
        case "country"       => country =  text
        case "postal_code"   => town = text
        case _               => // Hmm. Not sure what is expected here.

    }
  }
  Address(street,suburb,town,province,country,postalCode)
}
```

EDIT:

> I'm not sure how much more "functional" it can be.

But then again (note - this is again untested, I need to debug the getComponent, but the idea is clear, I hope. Corrections may arrive later)

```
def buildAddress(geocodeResponse: NodeSeq) : Address = {
  val addressNodes = geocodeResponse \\ "address_component"

  def getComponent(word:String) = {
        addressNodes.find{_ \ "type".head.text == word)  match {
        case Some(node) => node \ "long_name".text
        case _=> ""
        }
      }

  Address(getComponent("street_number")+getComponent("route"),
               getComponent("suburb"),
               getComponent("town"),
               getComponent("province"),
               getComponent("country"),
               getComponent("postalCode"))

}
```

Comment: Thanks. Just a small correction, for the sake of completeness: 1) the lazy val declaration must be inside the inner match; and 2) there must be a default case that handles the ignored nodes.

Comment: Your functional version is a much less efficient because you walk through the sequence several times. I think that the real problem is how to build a functional solution with the same performance.

Comment: @CheatEx, Agreed, it's less efficient. Performance wasn't mentioned by the OP, though :) I don't see how to solve your "real problem", though - ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a fold to be more functional (and walk through the sequence only once). I'm not sure I'd prefer that to your code. But this way you have no var (a new address is created at each step)

```
addressNode.foldLeft(new Address("", "", "", "", "", "")){(a, node) => 
  lazy val text = (node \ "long_name").text  
  (node \ "type").head.text match {
    case "street_number" => a.copy(street = a.street + text)
    ...
    case "locality" => a.copy(town = text)
    ...
   }
}
```

Comment: This is simultaneously ugly and elegant to my eye :) I like the building up of the complete object as you visit each (although it does make it difficult to know when an Address is really complete), but the use of a fold (to me) seems to be less clear than a for-comprehension...

Answer (score 1):

For an entirely different approach, you might consider [XML pickler combinators](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-scala-client/wiki/DevelopersGuide#XML_Pickler_Combinators), available in the [GData Scala client](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-scala-client).

```
def address: Pickler[Address] = 
   wrap(elem("address", 
           street ~ suburb ~ town ~ province ~ country ~ postalCode)) {
      Address.apply
   } {
      (a: Address) => new ~(a.street, a.suburb) ~ a.town ~ a.province ~ a.country ~ a.postalCode
   }

def postalCode: Pickler[String] = elem("postal_code", text)

// ... define picklers for street, suburb, town, province, country
```

This doesn't match your structure, but should give the flavor. The pickler combinator library is also [available on bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/anovstrup/xml-pickler-combinators/) as a separate library.