# Scala XML Marshaling using combinator from Scala GData

Tags: scala, xml-serialization

This questions is related to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664286/marshalling-unmarshalling-xml-in-scala/4675237#4675237) regarding the use of XML combinator which is part of the Google's Scala gdata client library found [here](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-scala-client/)

1. In the code posted, there was no parameter for elem("segment"...) Wouldn't this cause compiler to complain something like "could not find implicit value for parameter ns: (String, String)"
2. How do you generate XML elements without each tag having a name space prefix added. For example, the code I generated looks like:

   ```
   <yt:entry xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">
       <yt:title type="TextType">MyTitle</yt:title>
       <yt:summary>My Summary</yt:summary>
   </yt:entry>
   ```

But I don't want each tag to have the namespace prefix!! How do I use the combinator to generate such XML.

Here is what my pickler looks like:

```
def pickler: Pickler[YtPlaylist] = {
    (wrap (elem("entry",
           elem("title", text ~ attr("type", text))
           ~ elem("summary", text))(Uris.ytNs))
          (YtPlaylist.apply)
          ({p => new ~(p.title, p.titleType) ~ p.summary}))
}

case class YtPlaylist(title: String, titleType: String, summary: String)
```

The example I found on the web doesn't specify the namespace, but without it I always gets compilation error. How do I generate XML elements without namespace??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you will need to define a namespace. Use the `null` prefix to define the default namespace:

```
implicit val ns = (null: String, "http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007")
```

Comment: Thank you. It does exactly what I wants. On to my next question, how do I create an element with multiple namespace?

Comment: You can thank me by upvoting and accepting my answer (with the checkmark next to the answer). :-) I suggest posting your other question separately.

Comment: I would upvote and accept if I can, but it will require me getting 15 reputation first.

Comment: @YManYen No worries. :) I haven't seen your other question posted -- did you figure it out?

Comment: Thanks for asking. I eventually did figure it out.